# Assign a serializer field to current user id and "not" allow to edit it from BrowsableAPIRenderer on Django Rest Framework 2.3.13

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a below view, serializer and model. Using BrowsableAPIRenderer i render HTML page. I need to assign current user id to user_id field and hide the same from HTML rendering(not allow to edit and enter). I am using Django rest framework 2.3.13. Kindly help me to achieve this.

serializer.py

```
class TagOwnerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tag_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='tag_id')
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = TagOwner
        fields = ('url','tag_id','start_time','end_time','user_id')
```

views.py

```
class TagOwnerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    TagOwner table view set.
    """
    model = TagOwner
    queryset = TagOwner.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    serializer_class = TagOwnerSerializer
    renderer_classes = (BrowsableAPIRenderer, JSONRenderer,JSONPRenderer,XMLRenderer,YAMLRenderer)
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter ,filters.OrderingFilter)
    filter_class = TagOwnerFilter
    #search_fields = ('tag_id',)
    ordering_fields = '__all__'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            if not user:
                return []
            return TagOwner.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)
        public_tags = TagReads.objects.filter(public=True).values_list('tag_id').distinct()
        return TagOwner.objects.filter(tag_id__in=public_tags)

    def create(self,request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           user=self.request.user.id
           serializer.save(user_id = user)
           return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models.py

```
class TagOwner(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=False,db_column='user_id',)
    tag_id = models.OneToOneField('Tags',on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,db_column='tag_id',)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tag_owner'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself.

serializer.py

```
class TagOwnerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
      tag_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='tag_id')
      user_id = serializers.Field(source='user_id')
      #user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True,default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

      class Meta:
         model = TagOwner
         fields = ('url','tag_id','start_time','end_time','user_id')
```

views.py

```
class TagOwnerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
TagOwner table view set.
"""
    model = TagOwner
    queryset = TagOwner.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    serializer_class = TagOwnerSerializer
    renderer_classes = (BrowsableAPIRenderer, JSONRenderer,JSONPRenderer,XMLRenderer,YAMLRenderer)
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter ,filters.OrderingFilter)
    filter_class = TagOwnerFilter
    #search_fields = ('tag_id',)
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                if not user:
                        return []
                return TagOwner.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)
        public_tags = TagReads.objects.filter(public=True).values_list('tag_id').distinct()
        return TagOwner.objects.filter(tag_id__in=public_tags)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.user_id = self.request.user.id
```

This worked perfectly for me.